# Injecting JSON parameter in nativeQuery of Spring JPA

Tags: spring-data, postgresql-9.3, jsonb

I have a table with a JSONB column. In my project I am using Spring JPA and to query that column I want to use nativeQuery. My problem is to inject varibale into the query like below:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_json -> 'attributes' @> '{\"Param1\": \"" + :param + "\"}' ")
    List<Items> findByParameter(@Param("param") String param);
```

The above query does not work as param is not considered as JPA parameter. I am wondering if anyone knows how to do this? or I should do it in another way?

Comment: You use `@Param("param1") ` but try to reference a param named 'param'

Comment: @AlanHay It was a typo, I edited the question.

Comment: @sansari did you find out how to do this? I am looking at something similar

Comment: @BB It is not possible to inject parameter like that, I ended up to build the query by concatenating parameters to the query.